# Why must overloaded operators be declared public?

Tags: c#-4.0, operator-overloading

I wanted to overload an operator in a class , and have it private so that it could only be used from within the class.
However, when I tried to compile I got the error message "User-defined operator ... must be declared static and public:

Why do they have to be public?

Comment: A related question is: If you're only going to use it from within your class, why does it need to be an operator?

Comment: Yes, that is an obvious workaround. But I want to know why I will have to do a workaround. Using actual operators makes maths equations look like maths equations

Comment: Could you post and example? I'm really interested in see how this could be useful only inside the class.

Comment: Essentially I was using my class in a way that I didn't want available externally - the class was a rotation matrix, which shouldn't be externally changeable in ways such as adding them together, or scaling them. However, to create some of the Rotation Matrices, it was necessary to do several additions and multiplications of the class, essentially treating it as a normal, manipulatable matrix without writing a whole other class

Comment: So perhaps the reason it is not available is because it would allow poor design

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer half part of your question you may see the blog post by Eric Lippert.

[Why are overloaded operators always static in C#?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx)

> Rather, the question we should be asking ourselves when faced with a
>   potential language feature is "does the compelling benefit of the
>   feature justify all the costs?" And costs are considerably more than
>   just the mundane dollar costs of designing, developing, testing,
>   documenting and maintaining a feature. There are more subtle costs,
>   like, will this feature make it more difficult to change the type
>   inferencing algorithm in the future? Does this lead us into a world
>   where we will be unable to make changes without introducing backwards
>   compatibility breaks? And so on.
>
> In this specific case, the compelling benefit is small. If you want to
>   have a virtual dispatched overloaded operator in C# you can build one
>   out of static parts very easily. For example:

```
public class B {
    public static B operator+(B b1, B b2) { return b1.Add(b2); }
    protected virtual B Add(B b2) { // ...
```

> And there you have it. So, the benefits are small. But the costs are
>   large. C++-style instance operators are weird. For example, they break
>   symmetry. If you define an operator+ that takes a C and an int, then
>   c+2 is legal but 2+c is not, and that badly breaks our intuition about
>   how the addition operator should behave.

For your question's other part: *Why they should be public*.

I was not able to find any authentic source, but IMO, if they are not going to be public, and may be used inside a class only, then this can be done using a simple private method, rather than an overloaded operator.

You may see the blog post by RB Whitaker

[Operator Overloading](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-operator-overloading)

> All operator overloads must be public and static, which should make
>   sense, since we want to have access to the operator throughout the
>   program, and since it belongs to the class as a whole, rather than any
>   specific instance of the class.

Comment: Yes, but internal operators could be interesting too. Dont limit the reasoning to private.

Comment: This does not answer the question .. the op asked "Why do they have to be public?" ..  +1 @InBetween, there is no reason why they can't be private and it will be quite useful .. saying you can get around it doesn't mean it shouldn't be there